# Google Scholar / Articles manually-listed on personal profile don't appear in search

Tags: google-scholar

I have a Google Scholar profile (https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=2vlGfLcAAAAJ). I have manually added missing papers, and they are listed on the profile. However, they are not indexed and do not appear on Google Scholar search.

I have reviewed all instructions on Google Scholar's help pages and could not find a solution to the problem. Any thoughts why this is so and how to fix this?

I will much appreciate your kind advice.

Comment: That's really a question you'd need to ask the google scholar folks...